# clickable links in eclipse that will open a file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've got a really big project in eclipse, with tons of subdirectories.  So I forget where I put stuff.  Right now I have a little reminder file with paths like this:

product/webapp/catalog/product/ProductForms.xml

So then I have to navigate to that file.  Is it possible to add some kind of formatting to that path so I can click on it and eclipse will open that file in the editor in a new tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperlinking is handled in the preferences (window > preferences), under general > editors > text editors > hyperlinking.

However, a better solution to your real problem of locating files in a large project is probably the Resource Locator which you can access by hitting the key combination ctrl-shift-R. Just type a partial file name and all the matching files in your project/workspace will be listed.